# MARS MIPS Which Branch to use to check if numbers are evenly divisible

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your first number:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter your second number:"
prompt3: .asciiz "Your Number was evenly divisible by the second number!"

.text

main:
li $s0, 0   #Sets $s0 0
li $v0, 4   #Get user input
la $a0, prompt  #Displays "Enter your first number:"
syscall

li $v0, 5   #Gets users integer
syscall
move $t0, $v0   #Stores user input to $t0

li $v0 4    #Get user input
la $a0 prompt2  #Display prompt 2
syscall

li $v0 5    #Get int from user
syscall
move $t1, $v0

divu $t0, $t1  #Divides $t0/$t1
mfhi $t3
bnez $t3, exit



exit:
li $v0 10
syscall
```

The program I am trying to write is supposed to take two integer inputs from the user and divide them. If the number is evenly divisible by the second number then I will display "Prompt3:".

I have written most of it and it all seemed to work out, but I am having trouble with the conditional statement.

Comment: Which branch instruction you should use depends on how you want the flow of your program to look, so that's for you to decide. The condition you want to check for is if the remainder equals zero, and there are two branch instructions dealing with equality; `beq` and `bne`. So use one of those.

Comment: Thank you. So far my additional code looks like this

li $s0, 0                  #Set $s0 = 0
beq $t3, $s0 exit     #compares if $t3 == #s0 (in this case $s0 ==0)

exit:
la $a0 prompt3       #Displays prompt 3 ("Your Number is evenly divisible)
li $v0 10                 #exit the program
syscall       

Not sure if I am doing this right. Do I have to set $s0 == 0 in order to compare the answer if $t3 == 0?

Comment: There's already a register that's hardwired to always have the value zero: `$zero` (or `$0`).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong pseudoinstruction (`div/3`).

You should use `div` or `divu` then `mfhi` to obtain the remainder of the integer division and then test that remainder to see if it's zero or not.
E.g.:

```
divu $t0, $t1
mfhi $t3
bnez $t3, exit
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited just like you said, but its still not working for me for some reason. It does not jump to the exit: section when $t0 is evenly divided by $t1.

Comment: @Rorix: You forgot to add these lines between the `bnez $t3, exit`and the `exit` label: `la $a0, prompt3` `li $v0, 4` `syscall`. These lines are the ones that print your `prompt3` text.